# Short Story like "Resurrection Days"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia

Looking for a pulp short-story with the following plot elements: man dies; wakes in dystopia governed by women; makes bacon using a mental-machine.

The theme is similar to Wilson Tucker's '80's novel, *Resurrection Days*. Tucker wrote a short version in 1960. but neither the novel nor the short story he wrote is the one I'm looking for.

I believe the story I'm looking for would predate Tucker's story.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! I've edited your post, to try to focus attetion on the work you're looking for, instead of Tucker's work. You can [edit] the post again, if you feel I've changed too much.

Comment: You may also want to look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/80867) for ideas on additional info you could add to your post to help identify the story. Anything you recall that would be a distionction between this story and the other you mention would be good.